# How would I find the sum of this infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms

Any help with steps would be much appreciated. I know how to solve simpler versions of this problem but can't seem to figure this one out. Thank you!

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{5^{3n}}$$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence#Series.2C_sum_to_n_terms

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n}{5^{3n}}$?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just changed it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Is your problem the $n$ in the numerator?  Can you do $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{2}{5^{3n}}$? Then consider $\frac d{dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{x^{3n}}$.  Evaluate it once by summing the series before differentiating, then by differentiating term by term.  Finally set $x=5$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to \infty instead of to n. Corrected the problem.

Comment: @Dr.MV I have updated to follow the question.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> If one has yet to learn derivatives, then the finite sum can be evaluated using straightforward arithmetic and the trivial sum $2n=\sum_{j=1}^n (2)$.  We proceed accordingly.

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
S_n &=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2i}{5^{3i}} \tag 1\\\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{5^{3i}}\sum_{j=1}^i(2) \tag 2\\\\
&=2\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=j}^{n}\frac{1}{5^{3i}} \tag 3\\\\
&=2\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{5^35^{-3j}-5^{-3n}}{5^3-1}\right) \tag 4\\\\
&=\frac{2(5^3)}{5^3-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(5^{-3}\right)^j-\frac{2n(5^{-3n})}{5^3-1}\tag 5\\\\
&=\frac{2(5^3)}{5^3-1}\left(\frac{1-5^{-3n}}{5^3-1}\right)-\frac{2n(5^{-3n})}{5^3-1} \tag 6\\\\
&=\frac{5^{-3n}\left(-124n+125^{n+1}-125\right)}{7688} \tag 7
\end{align}$$

In the limit as $n\to \infty$, we find that

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{2i}{5^{3i}}=\frac{125}{7688}$$

---

**NOTES:**

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we used the trivial sum $2n=\sum_{j=1}^n (2)$.

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we changed the order of summation.

In obtaining $(4)$, we summed the geometric series $\sum_{i=j}^n\frac{1}{5^{3i}}$.

In going from $(4)$ to $(5)$, we simply split the sum into two parts and carried out the second sum.

In obtaining $(6)$, we summed the geometric series $\sum_{j=1}^n 5^{-3j}$.

And in arriving at $(7)$, we simply gathered terms and used a common denominator.

Comment: I think I need to review some of the algebra especially for step 4, but seeing each step is really helpful along with the explanations. Thanks for taking the time to go through the solution!

Comment: @kim You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Step $4$ is just the sum of the geometric progression.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{5^{3n}}$, then
\begin{align}
S-\frac{1}{5^3}S
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{5^{3n}}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{5^{3n+3}}\\
&=\left(\frac{2}{5^3}+\frac{4}{5^6}+\frac{6}{5^9}+\cdots\right)
-\left(\frac{2}{5^6}+\frac{4}{5^9}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac{2}{5^3}+\frac{2}{5^6}+\frac{2}{5^9}+\cdots\\
&=\frac{\frac{2}{5^3}}{1-5^{-3}}\\
&=\frac{1}{62}.
\end{align}
Therefore $S=\displaystyle\frac{125}{124}\cdot\frac{1}{62}=\frac{125}{7688}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Take the 2 out of the summation. Then the remaining series is an Arithmetic Geometric progression with a convergent sum(why?).
     $$2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{5^{3n}}=2\left(\frac{1}{5^{3}}+\frac{2}{5^{6}}+\frac{3}{5^{9}}+ \cdots+\frac{1+\left(n-1\right)1}{\left(5^{3}\right)^{n-1}}+\cdots \right)$$